# Get value returned by useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Get value returned by *useState* when *state updates first time*.

In following code :
*Initial value is **0*** and after *clicking on button value will be **1***.I want to store ***value1*** in ***firstValue*** and ***value2*** in ***secondValue*** and these values must be **immutable**.

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);  
// const firstValue = 
// const secondValue =

  return <button onClick={() => setCount(count+1)}> value {count}</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App count={0}/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-3vo65ZXn5pfsCfGM5H55X+SmwJHBlyNHPwRmWAPgJnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-qVsF1ftL3vUq8RFOLwPnKimXOLo72xguDliIxeffHRc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

> *Value will be stored only ***first and second click*** of button and these values must be ***immutable.****

**Expected Output**

```
firstValue = value1
secondValue = value2
```

Comment: I think you have not mentioned where you get `value1` and `value2`. value 1 will equal to `count` and value 2 will equal to `count + 1`?

Comment: you need to explain the story why you need prev, current state, and where you want to use.

Comment: when we click on button first time then state of count changes and returns value 1. and i want to store that value1 in firstValue.but i want firsttime immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps another state variable can be responsible for this part?

```js
const MAX = 2
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState([]);
  function onClick () {
    if (count < MAX) {
      setValues([...values, count])
    }
    setCount(count+1)
  }
  
  const [firstValue, secondValue] = values

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}> value {count}</button>
      <p>first value: {firstValue}</p>
      <p>second value: {secondValue}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App count={0}/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-3vo65ZXn5pfsCfGM5H55X+SmwJHBlyNHPwRmWAPgJnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-qVsF1ftL3vUq8RFOLwPnKimXOLo72xguDliIxeffHRc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `value1` is `count`'s previous state, and `value2` is `count`'s current state.

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  //Initialize the variables
  let firstValue = count;
  let secondValue = count;

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        firstValue = secondValue; // set first value equal to previous count value
        secondValue = count + 1; // set second value equal to new count value
        setCount(count + 1); // update the state
      }}
    >
      value {count}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Not sure this is optimal solution, but a way using `useRef`
- gather's all the values not only first two, but yes key names can be altered as per your convenience

```js
    function App() {
      const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);  
      const values = React.useRef({});
  
      const updateValue = () => {
        setCount(count+1);
        // get previous values using spread, and then add the dynamic using square brackets
        values.current = {...values.current, ["value" + (count+1)]: count+1 }
      }
      // you may require this values.current
      console.log(values.current)
      return <button onClick={() => updateValue() }> value {count}</button>;
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App count={0}/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-3vo65ZXn5pfsCfGM5H55X+SmwJHBlyNHPwRmWAPgJnM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-qVsF1ftL3vUq8RFOLwPnKimXOLo72xguDliIxeffHRc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                import {
                    useState,
                    useEffect
                } from 'react'
                export default function App() {
                    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
                    const [values, setValues] = useState({
                        firstValue: 0,
                        secondValue: 0
                    });
                    useEffect(() => {
                        setValues({
                            firstValue: values.secondValue,
                            secondValue: count
                        });
                    }, [count, setCount]);

                    console.log("first value", values.firstValue);
                    console.log("second value", values.secondValue)
                    return <button onClick = {
                            () => setCount(count + 1)
                        } > value {
                            count
                        } <
                        /button>;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function usePrevious(value){
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(()=>{
    ref.current = value;
  },[value]);

  return ref.current;
}

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);  

  const firstValue = usePrevious(count)
  const secondValue = count

  return <button onClick={() => setCount(count+1)}> value {count}</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App count={0}/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```